# Метод простой итераций

Tags: матрицы, c++

Что не правильно, компилятор вообще молчит, (может не работает)
Проверьте, пожалуйста!

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
main()

{

float a[4][4],B[4],x[4];

int i,j;

printf("vvedite chisla");

for(i=1;i<=4;i++)
{for(j=1;j<=4;j++)
{printf("%f",&a[i][j]);}

}
printf("vvedite B\n");

for(i=1;i<=4;i++)

{printf("%f",&B[i]);

x[i]=B[i];}

for(i=1;i<=4;i++)

{for(j=1;j<=4;j++)

{x[i]+=a[i][j]*B[i];

}
}
for(i=1;i<=4;i++)

{printf("6.4f",x[i]);}

getch();
```

Comment: 1. Выведите код правильно (выделите весь код и нажмите CTRL+K);
2. Покажите ошибки, которые выводит компилятор.

Comment: Массивы в C++ от индексируются от нуля. Дальше не смотрел.

Comment: О, уже лучше, а теперь отформатируйте, чтобы можно было нормально читать. Хорошо?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(i=1;i<=4;i++)
{
    for(j=1;j<=4;j++)
    {
        printf("%f",&a[i][j]);
    }
}
```

и т.д. как уже написали -

1. "массивы индексируются от 0"!
2. вы постоянно ПИШЕТЕ в стандартный вывод (консоль). А читать кто будет?